# Unable to access Cassandra on same network

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to run a demo of Spark Cassandra Kafka integration on an Azure VMs.
I did run the demo locally and i got result . When i try to connect to Cassandra VM i got the following error:

> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.1.0.6:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [/10.1.0.6:9042] Cannot connect))

I have 3 (connected) VMs running on CentOs 7, they can ping each other.
I have disabled their firewall.
I also added inbound ports in the security group.

This may help: when I use nmap to check some specific ports such as 9042 on each machine it shows that it is open locally but when I check other addresses ports it shows that they are closed.

> Versions INFO: spark-version : 2.3.1 Scala-version : 2.11.7
>   java-version : 1.8.0_181 cqlsh: 5.0.1  |  cassandra 3.9.0   |   CQL
>   spec 3.4.2

Comment: The following problem is probably due Cassandra version. You can use bitnami cassandra to solve as @charles mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Azure VMs in the same Vnet can access each other. And you have checked that with ping each other.

You can check follow the steps:

1. Check the Security rules if allow the traffic to the port 9042 for all VMs.
2. Check if the service listens to the port 9042 and can access locally.
3. Check if the firewall allows the traffic from port 9042.

If you don't mind, you can dissociate the NSG from the network interface of VMs when testing the connection and only remain the NSG associated with the Subnet.

Comment: 1) In fact, I did check security rules to allow traffic to the port 9042 inbound and outbound on NSG level and the network interface level on each VM.
2) let's suppose I'm running Cassandra server on VM3 with local address 10.1.0.6 in which i can start cqlsh normally with the following message : Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
3) I have disabled the firewall on all VMs after allowing port 9042.

Comment: Maybe this could help : 
I am on vm3 with local address 10.1.0.6 
When I run : nmap -p 9042 localhost  ==>  it shows TCP port 9042 is open
But when I run : nmap -p 9042 10.1.0.6  ==> it shows TCP port 9042 is closed

Comment: If you run the command `nmap` in the VM3? And when you use comand `nmap -p 9042 10.1.0.6`, are you on other VM?

Comment: no I am on the same VM with the address 10.1.0.6 ... even when I try nmap from another VM i get the same message (closed)

Comment: In fact the problem is Cassandra related , because when I run kafka on multiple nodes(VMs) they can reach each other through another port

Comment: Is it Cassandra related? Could you test another port with the command `nmap`?

Comment: opened ports are not visible through nmap search ... because kafka is running perfectly between the 2 VMs (connection established and messages are being sent) , Should I change cassandra address to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ? this is not recommended in cassandra documentation

Comment: Address 127.0.0.1 usually means the local machine, and 0.0.0.0 means all the machines. It's not safe. And have you solved your problem?

Comment: Still have the same problem even when I changed the address.
Now it's back to 127.0.0.1 and i'm still troubleshooting , If you have any recommended solution

Comment: @CherifRzouga How about the document [Bitnami Cassandra For Microsoft Azure](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/infrastructure/cassandra/). Maybe you can get help from it.

Comment: Ok I will try it ... But isn't there any solution to the address problem

Comment: Address? I do not know much about Cassandra. If the problem is related to it, I can provide no more help. You can get the help from me for other related problems.

Comment: Thanks , Is there any simple way to connect two VMs each on a unique virtual network using azure portal. Bitnami assocaite cassandra vm to a new virtual network

Comment: The easiest way is to set up Vnet Peering. It's simple to do it. You can follow this document [Connect virtual networks with virtual network peering using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal). Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes it did work. Now I have authentication problem. I will continue on my own.
Thanks for your help